# Replaced Windows 7 with Ubuntu 13.04 but won't boot from internal HDD

Tags: installation, boot, 13.04

The installation went fine until I restarted. I remember enabling boot from removable disk and was thinking of disabling it as it boot up. Pressed F8 nothing happened. Instead it went straight to the Purple Ubuntu loading screen. If I try to boot without the usb, it just gives me a blank black screen with a blinking _.

I am fairly new to this and I am hoping for a fix. Thanks in advance.

Comment: might want to check this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/296163/black-screen-on-login/296188#296188) out

Comment: We don't post answers into questions here. Please provide your solution as an answer in the "Your Answer" section. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question.

Comment: @gertvdijk - Duly noted and edited it out. It wont let me post the answer but I will after it permits me to.

Comment: @EliahKagan I found them before I saw your comment. Still, thank you.

Comment: @proselyte Ah I see. Yeah, after you've gained more reputation you'll lose all those restrictions.

Answer (score -1):

Install from USB or DVD?
If you use a USB-Stick for the installation, it could be that the bootloader (grub2 i think) is written on the USB-Stick.
So if you remove it, the Machine couldnt boot..

Look at the installation were the bootloader will be installed (were the partition window is).

If that doesnt work, burn a dvd and try with it. That should work!

Have a nice day ;-)

Comment: Please note that as mentioned in the comments, the OP already has an answer to his question, but he isn't able to post it as such at this time.

Comment: @MrManfred I recommend expanding this answer to explain *how* one would go about "Look[ing] at the installation [where] the bootloader will be installed." Remember, Ubuntu has already been installed; it probably does not need to be reinstalled. Only the boot loader is likely to need reinstallation.