# Dell inspiron N51100 black screen after login

Tags: drivers, screen

After a normal login screen in Ubuntu 13.10 I get a black screen with only my cursor.

I tried to open in recovery mode to adjust the driver settings but that didn't work. I get an error that the screen can not be found.

I really hope you can help!

Comment: Did you try uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers completely?

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 and then add the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:unity-team/staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

and reboot, hope it will work.

If it doesn’t work then [click here for further workaround](https://askubuntu.com/a/296188/192102)
and 
 [here for wiki how.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/BlankScreen)

Comment: I get a warning: could not find the package list for PPA: unity-team staging

Comment: U need to connect to internet..skip first two commands

Comment: ctrl+alt+f1 doesn't open virtual console during black screen for me.

Comment: i dont know why , but its working for me.

Comment: Unable to fetch http://.. Could not resolve '...?redirect' I think my network won allow me to download it. Ill try another connection later. Thanks so far!

Comment: I've got a working Internet connection. Still got same warning. Could not find package list for PPA: Unity-team staging.

Comment: I have tried everything i know , well have you checked the second link for wiki how , i has deep information about issue ,may be that could help you, and the better option is to reinstall it .